# Jackson TreeModel vs Databinding

Tags: jackson, jackson2, jackson-databind, jackson-modules

I am trying to think of scenario to use Jackson [TreeModel](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-node-tree-model) and Databinding API ([Object mapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)). When you would chose one again the another ?

Answer (score 1):

`URL`-es you added to a question contain the answer in the overview.

[Working with Tree Model](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-node-tree-model)

> We’ll use JsonNode for various conversions as well as adding,
>   modifying and removing nodes.

and

[Intro to the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

> This write-up is focused on understanding the Jackson ObjectMapper
>   class – and how to serialize Java objects into JSON and deserialize
>   JSON string into Java objects.

I can only confirm that. `99%` of examples I had to serialize `Java` `POJO` classes to `JSON` and vice versa. When I need to change a little `JSON` I use `Tree Model` to avoid whole serializing and deserializing process.